# Terraform module structure

Tags: terraform

I had a flat structure of all my `.tf` files and want to migrate to a folder (i.e. `module`) based set up so that my code is clearer.

For example I have moved my instance and elastic IP (eip) definitions in separate folders

```
/terraform
 ../instance
   ../instance.tf
 ../eip
    ../eip.tf
```

In my `instance.tf`:

```
resource "aws_instance" "rancher-node-production" {}
```

In my `eip.tf`:

```
module "instance" {
  source = "../instance"
}


resource "aws_eip" "rancher-node-production-eip" {
  instance = "${module.instance.rancher-node-production.id}"
```

However when running `terraform plan`:

> Error: resource 'aws_eip.rancher-node-production-eip' config: "rancher-node-production.id" is not a valid output for module "instance"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of modules as black boxes that you can't "reach" into. To get data out of a module, that module needs to export that data with an `output`. So in your case, you need to declare the `rancher-node-production` id as an output of the `instance` module.

If you look at the error you're getting, that's exactly what it's saying: `rancher-node-production.id` is not a valid output of the module (because you never defined it as an output).

Anyway here's what it would look like.

```
# instance.tf
resource "aws_instance" "rancher-node-production" {}

output "rancher-node-production" {
    value = {
        id = "${aws_instance.rancher-node-production.id}"
    }
}
```

Hope that fixes it for you.